PyQt6 Qtableview and Qsql
In pyqt6 I have a Qtableview for customer orders. I want to achieve two functionality in that table. A user to click in the product column which will fire up a Dialogue window where we can find a list of product from database and once the product is selected I want Unit of Measurement column to autopopulate the selected products packs. There is very little info on Qtableview and documentation just goes over my head. If anyone could point me to direction that will be a great help. Thanks
I tried copying some format from the book I was referring to achieve this and came up with something like this but this does not seem to work.
Is tableview the right way to go about this problem all together???
class TableViewModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self,data):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = data
        self.header = ["No.","Products", "UOM", "Ordered", "Supplied"]
        
    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int = ...):
        if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Horizontal and role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            # return f"Column {section + 1}"
            return self.header[section]
        
    def data(self,index,role):
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            if index.column() == 2:
                return "data from database"
        return
        
    def rowCount(self, index):
        return 
        
    def columnCount(self, index):
        return 4
    
    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole:
            self._data[index.row()][index.column()] = value
            return True
        return False
    
    def flags(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            return Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEditable


rowCount() should return a valid integer (probably len(self._data), but you're not telling us what data actually is), right now it returns None, which is wrong.

Thanks for your answer. This is where i am so dumb. Data is something user should be inserting in the table say their orders. I tried passing empty list in the tableview then I was not able to edit the table. Should i be using qtablewidget instead?

I know what is the purpose of data, but you didn't explain what type of object it is, nor its contents. If you pass an empty list, the table will be empty and therefore there can be nothing to edit. Qt item models and views require some patience in learning, before trying to create your own model without proper understanding, I suggest to start by studying the Model/View Programming guide and begin by using existing and finished models such as QStandardItemModel (and QSqlTableModel if you're using databases).
